# Move particular subdirectory (and all files in it) to another path

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu

I am trying to move all folders (all content within the folder) named "RAW" located under "~/Pictures" to my "~Desktop" directory. There other folders in the parent folder of the RAW folder.

In my "Pictures" folder I have the following structure:

```
~/Pictures/<Event Name>/RAW/
```

There are files under ~/Pictures// which I don't want to move

I want to create similar structure in the Desktop folder:

```
~/Desktop/<Event Name>/RAW/
```

I have managed to create similar structure in the Desktop directory using:

```
cd ~/Pictures
find . type -d -name RAW -exec mkdir -p ~/Desktop/{} \;
```

How do I now move the all folders named RAW in the respective directory structure on the Desktop?

Copying is not an option since I do not have enough disk space!

Comment: Why not `for i in Pictures/[limit as needed]*; do mv "$i" Desktop/${i#Pictures/}; done`?

Comment: Actually there are other files in the parent folder of the RAW folder but only I want to move the RAW subfolder and its contents and not the other files.

Answer (score 3):

Just do:

```
mv ~/Pictures/RAW/ ~/Desktop/
```